# Showing that a limit based on the stationary distribution of a Markov chain is zero.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, solution-verification

> Let $\{f_t:t\geqslant 0\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a countable space $\mathcal X$ and $\pi$ a measure on $\mathcal X$ with $\sum_{y\in \mathcal X}\pi(y)=M<\infty$ Suppose that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f_t(y)=0$ for all $y\in\mathcal X$ and there exists $B<\infty$ such that $|f_t(y)|\leqslant B$ for all $t,y$. Then
>
> $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{y\in\mathcal X}\pi(y)f_t(y) = 0. $$

My argument is that since $\{f_t\}$ is uniformly bounded, we may pick $B<\infty$ such that $|f_t(y)|\leqslant B$ for all $t,y$, from which for any $\varepsilon>0$ we may choose $T$ large enough that $f_t(y) <\frac\varepsilon{MB}$ for $t\geqslant T$. Then for $t\geqslant T$ we have
$$
\sum_{y\in\mathcal X}\pi(y)f_t(y) \leqslant MB\cdot\frac\varepsilon{MB} = \varepsilon,
$$
from which it follows that the limit is zero. Is this correct?

Comment: Your hypothesis is not clear. What does $lim f(t)=0$ mean?

Comment: Your proof does not  make much sense. You are not even taking limit as $ t \to \infty$ in your proof. Where exactly did you need $t$ large in your argument?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be $f_t(y)$ and that we may choose $T$ large so that $|f_t(y)|\leqslant B$ for all $t,y$. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I hope that my question is clear now - I assume that was the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not valid since $T$ may depend on $y$. This result is immediate consequence of DCT.

For a proof without DCT note that the tail sums of the series $\sum_y \pi (y)$ tend to $0$. Hence there is a finite set $F=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_N\}$ such that $\sum_{y \notin F}\pi (y) <\epsilon$. Now $\sum f(y)\pi (y) = \sum_{y \notin F} f(y)\pi (y)+\sum f(y_i)\pi (y_i)$. Use the bound for $f$ in the first term and let $t \to \infty$ in the second term.

Comment: What dominating function would we use?

Comment: The dominating function is $\rho(y)=B\pi (y)$. @Math1000

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @Math1000 I have even added another proof without measure theory.

Comment: To me the argument via DCT is more intuitive, but it doesn't hurt to include another proof.